# Jmeter Digest Authentication

Tags: jmeter, digest-authentication

Is it possible to use digest auth in jmeter.

When server answers 401 with auth header

(etc: WWW_Authenticate :SP Digest realm="SD Digest Authentication Realm", qop="auth", nonce="MTYyNTE2Mjc5MDE4NDo0ZTQ0NWJjM2Y0MWQ4OGFlMzQyODRmMjEzNWViMTYwNQ==")

on the first request from client and then client must resend original request with properly formed auth headers?

I try to use HTTP Authorization Manager with http client 4, but no luck.

Jmeter does not send any auth header and does not repeat original request.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this `/` from "Domain" section, I don't think it's applicable for Digest authentication, it's more for [NTLM and/or Kerberos](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter). But given server sends proper [WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) header even given wrong HTTP Authorization Manager configuration you should be seeing the Authorization request header

Apart from this I cannot reproduce your issue using simple [Apache web server](https://httpd.apache.org/) with [mod_auth_digest](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_digest.html)

[image]

Comment: I'm doing exact the same, but second request does not appear.
Can it be beacause of string **"SP Digest"** instead of "Digest"?


"WWW_Authenticate : **SP Digest** realm="SD Digest Authentication Realm", qop="auth", nonce="MTYyNTE2Mjc5MDE4NDo0ZTQ0NWJjM2Y0MWQ4OGFlMzQyODRmMjEzNWViMTYwNQ=="